# Как сделать плавное перетекание текста, чтобы начинался в одном столбце, а заканчивался в другом?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок разбитый на 2 столбца. Как сделать так, чтобы весь текст начинался сразу под заголовком в первом столбце, а дальше плавно перетекал в правый при различном объеме текста. Т.е. начало это "текст рыба", а его продолжение в "продолжение текста" и чтобы он бы неделимый. Блок должен сохранять адаптивность и выходить за пределы блока не должен.

Можно ли это реализовать с помощью только стилей или без скриптов никак не обойтись?

```css
.percent50 {
 width:50%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="percent50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/180x135/" />
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>текст рыба</p>
</div><div class="percent50">
<p>продолжение текста</p>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS Multi-column Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

```css
.article {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180x135/">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```